# Default value for Parameter Ms Access Query

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2013, default-value

i have ms access query like this :

```
PARAMETERS prmORIGINCODE Text ( 255 ), 
           prmORIGIN Text ( 255 ),
           prmSERVICECODE Text ( 255 ),
           prmDESTINATION Text ( 255 ), 
           prmDESTCODE Text ( 255 ), 
           prmSTARTDATE Text ( 255 ), 
           prmENDDATE Text ( 255 );

SELECT 
    SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, 
    SUMMARY.DESTINATION, 
    Count(SUMMARY.CNOTE_NO) AS CountOfCNOTE_NO
FROM SUMMARY
WHERE (
        (
          (SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE) = [prmORIGINCODE]) AND
            ((SUMMARY.CNOTE_SERVICES_CODE) = [prmSERVICECODE]) AND 
            ((SUMMARY.ORIGIN) = [prmORIGIN]) AND ((SUMMARY.DEST_CODE) = [prmDESTCODE]) AND 
        ((SUMMARY.TGL_DATA) >= [prmSTARTDATE] And (SUMMARY.TGL_DATA) <= [prmENDDATE])
      )
GROUP BY 
    SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, 
    SUMMARY.DESTINATION, 
    SUMMARY.TGL_DATA, 
    SUMMARY.ORIGIN, 
    SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE, 
    SUMMARY.DEST_CODE, 
    SUMMARY.CNOTE_SERVICES_CODE;
```

My Question is:

How to give default value to Query parameter? i want the query give me result even when i'm not give value to parameter (i want to show all record when i'm not give value to parameter).

Some of my code in C# :

```
OleDbCommand accessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            accessCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, mycon);
            accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmORIGINCODE", "BDO");
            accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmORIGIN", "BDO10000");
            accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmSERVICECODE", "REG15");
            accessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmORIGINCODE", "BDO");
            using (OleDbDataReader myReader = accessCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
                myTable.Load(myReader);
                return myTable;
            }
```

Comment: Need to write a `IF` Condition in this scenario will be easier. One where you have parameters. in another where u dont have any parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change design of your database. select column in design mode and put a default value for it. If you don't write a specific value for this parameter, the default value will considered.